# intersection form for non-compact manifold

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Can we define the intersection form 
$H_{k}(M) \times H_{n-k}(M) \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ for non-compact manifold $M^n$?

Comment: That would be a tall order, since any finite CW-complex is of homotopy type of a non-compact manifold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we can, provided that $M$ is oriented. Just use the Poincare duality isomorphism between $H_k(M)$ and $H^{n-k}_c(M)$.